# how to create folded brochure like in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

am trying to create a brochure in Photoshop. But how do you get such a folded effect i.e. when I want to show the brochure to someone else as a preview, I want to make it look as if it's folded (like in the image below):

[image]
(image courtesy: http://maxcdn.photoshoplady.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/design-a-proper-folded-brochure-l.png)

Comment: Understand I right? You want to show your  brochure folded in Photoshop?  Create your  brochure, print it, fold it, take a picture, ...

Comment: @Kurt does every designer do that, really? there must be some way in the software to do it

Comment: Those are only three rectangles with some shades to give it a spatial look. Try creating each site of the brochure as one grouped layer, then transform them as in the picture above and add some shades.

Comment: I just wanted to say that the question is a little bit unclear. So suppose the broschure is ready you want a new image, that shows the broschure folded (right part of your picture)? Then follow the comment of @Gin-San.

Comment: I'm kind of with @Kurt. Print it out and photograph it. It will probably be less time and acida.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to GD.SE. To be able to help, we really need to know what you have tried and why it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get that by using a mock up.
Just download it and place your picture in the layer which they mentioned.

http://www.24psd.com/blank-tri-fold-brochure-template-mock-up/

Answer (score 0):

what Rijin mentioned is actually correct.

Normally for designers first we design the draft, & then we would actually find some nice mockup template to show the client so that they can visualize how are the actual print outs going to look like as a preview. This is quite common in our company here so that we can save time & avoid misunderstanding on both sides.

For me i personally use http://graphicburger.com/ for mockup resources. Download the mockup which you find suitable & replace the content by double clicking on the smart object layer.

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have also resorted to using premade mockup PSD files to show clients, because I don't want to spend the time creating my own. (even though the sample mockup doesn't show the 6th panel).

If you grab a mockup from someplace, you'll notice that there are one or more layers with "editable" content (clicking on the layers will open an embedded photoshop file, sometimes nested 2 levels down, where you replace their artwork with your own)

Those layers on the mockup file are treated with layer effects, shading, and distortion to yield a realistic look.

Answer (score 0):

all the above answers are applicable. but none of them mentioned "photoshop action" .. simply you can download a free photoshop action from tons of it online ... simply you can select the way your folded brochure would look like and place your design over a template then run the action and that's it.

you can pick any action you like from this [Link](http://www.actionuser.com/search/category/11/) or this [link](http://www.psdmockups.com/2013/12/3-panel-tri-fold-brochure-psd-mockups/) for PSD mockups and actions.

if those link are dead in the future, you can google "folding brochure Photoshop action" if not you may use a preset action or just do your own action.

and what is a photoshop action? it is a list of commands and transformation values you can do by yourself as if you are doing the folding brochure from scratch, a step by step. like dividing your design in three layers and preposition and rotate every layer to take the effect of a real folding brochure, and by adding some shadow and light effects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google "Brochure mockup PSD" or "trifold mockup PSD" and you will find many free and premium (paid) options to create mockup your file like the image you included. I use these frequently for my portfolio.